# Get last row inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a trigger that inserts a record into a diff table but I need to get that record that was inserted inside the trigger, how do I do it? There is no identity field, only account_nbr that is generated by a separate trigger on the insert table.

I don't know if there is sql statements to retrieve a row that was just inserted.

DB is Sql Server 2008.

Comment: I guess you are talking about the `Inserted` table - be aware: this pseudo-table can contain **multiple** rows in a trigger! (not just a single one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OUTPUT clause will give you back the records you have just inserted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

If you mean the rows inserted *before* the trigger invoked, they are in the `inserted` pseudo-table.

Comment: @Mitch - right; it is bad practice, but the trigger can do SELECT/OUTPUT/etc

Comment: Columns returned from OUTPUT reflect the data as it is after the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement has completed but before triggers are executed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx    Not sure if I'm understanding your intended use of OUTPUT? (it's late and brain is fuzzy!)

Comment: @Mitch I'm saying inside the trigger, which also completely sucks, architecture-wise. I'd actually rather redesign to avoid both this need *and* remove the trigger, but hard to advise on that without more context

Comment: any idea if mySQL has the equiv. of OUTPUT? I've been looking but unable to find it

Comment: @Will no idea, I'm afraid. It is new to SQL server (2008?), but I don't use mysql